# Update in a rawQuery() not working

Tags: android, sqlite

Im doing a update in my database but its not working.
This is my code:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {  
            MeusVeiculosLista mVeiculo = (MeusVeiculosLista) adapter.getItem(position); 
            VeiculosDAO veiculo = new VeiculosDAO(TrocaVeiculoActivity.this);
            veiculo.open();
            veiculo.atualizaAtivo();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            veiculo.close();                
        }
    });
```

This is the code method atualizaAtivo() where I do the update:

```
public void atualizaAtivo(){
    mDb.rawQuery("Update tb_veiculo set ativo = 0", null);

}
```

Im using the lita to test, and when I do the statement, it works, but Its not work in cell phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rawQuery` is not working in android for update. for this issue you have to use `SQLiteDatabase.Update` method like this:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("ativo", 0);
mDb.update("tb_veiculo", cv, null, null);
```

Comment: Do I have to put the full object in content values or just the column tha I want to update?

Comment: You're welcome @Roland . If you want to use where clause for your update method you can use third and fourth parameters.

Comment: Right, You might also want to do your update in a DB transaction using beginTransaction() and endTransaction() - see idiomatic example at http://android.codota.com/scenarios/527f776ada0ab642c1a725f3/android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase?tag=antelope

Comment: hey @drorw ! where is your catch exception statement in your code?

Comment: @MajidDaeiNejad - there is no catch statement. The try-finally ensures that we will end the transaction, even if an unchecked or runtime exception occurs in the try block. It's a good practice to close or free resources in "finally" blocks

Comment: @drorw - You mean no need `RollBack` Transaction or something else?

Comment: On successful update you call setTransactionSuccessful(). If it was called, endTransaction() will do commit, but if it was not called it will rollback the changes. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction()